# How to estimate optimal fees for transaction in bitcoind?

Tags: bitcoind, api, transaction-fees

As I understand, with the network congestion it's sometimes advisable to set a higher fee to process a transaction within a block or two. Is there some way to estimate the optimal fee through calls to bitcoind? I know there are [some online services](https://estimatefee.appspot.com/) that do those estimations, but I'd rather not rely on such external factors.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The other answer is outdated. `estimatefee` is deprecated.
You should use `estimatesmartfee`

> Please use estimatesmartfee for more intelligent estimates.
>   Estimates the approximate fee per kilobyte needed for a transaction to begin
>   confirmation within nblocks blocks. Uses virtual transaction size of transaction
>   as defined in BIP 141 (witness data is discounted).
>
> Arguments:
>   1. nblocks     (numeric, required)

**Example:**

```
bitcoin-cli estimatesmartfee 6
```

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried using the `estimatefee` [RPC call](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#estimatefee)? This will calculate the amount needed per kilobyte.

For example calling `bitcoin-cli estimatefee 2` would provide a fee per kb to try to get confirmed within 2 blocks.

https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#estimatefee

Comment: In fact, if you use any of the automatic send RPCs (`sendtoaddress` etc), and don't configure a manual feerate (the `-paytxfee` option), fee estimation will be used automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I am using https://bitcoinfees.net . They hare using Bitcoin Core's "estimatesmartfee" method. You can easily pick a transaction fee based on confirmation time.