# How to sweep a Bitcoin Core wallet?

Tags: bitcoind, transaction-fees, json-rpc, fee-estimation

I have created an account in a bitcoind wallet which has got some 1.055btc which has to be wiped out to **0.00BTC** to another account.  so the actual BTC has to be sent is 1.055 - transaction fee.

Is there any calculation for bitcoin to find transaction fee or any jsonrpc to find estimation fee like ethereum (balance - (gasprice*gaslimit)).

Answer (score 2):

With recent versions of bitcoind, you can use [`sendtoaddress`](http://chainquery.com/bitcoin-api/sendtoaddress) with the optional `subtractfeefromamount` argument.

```
sendtoaddress 123abc... 1.055 "" "" true
```

Creates a transaction with 1.055 BTC of inputs.  The destination address will receive a little less than 1.055 BTC, after an appropriate fee is subtracted.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to estimate the transaction fee (Skip to 3 if you want an automated way to send your entire balance).

1. You can use the Bitcoin cli. From [a previous answer on  how to
   estimate fees](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/50380/how-to-estimate-optimal-fees-for-transaction-in-bitcoind):

   ```
   bitcoin-cli estimatesmartfee 6
   ```
2. You can also use many webservices that focus on fee estimation:

   - https://estimatefee.com/
   - https://bitcoinfees.earn.com/
3. Finally, you could upload your private key to a wallet such as
   [electrum](https://electrum.org/) which will take care of fee estimation for you and
   ensure all your bitcoin is transferred.